# хэш-функция методом умножения

Tags: python, хеширование

Вот функция реализована мной, но заполняется таблица странно, в первой ячейке аж 2 значения, во второй ни одного. Правильно ли?

```
def hashing_f(key):
mod = key * 0.618033
result = int(len(hash_table) * (mod - int(mod)))
return result
```

---

```
def insert(hash_table, key, value):
hash_key = hashing_f(key)
hash_table[hash_key].append(value)
```

Comment: hash_table не определенна

Comment: По идее result - одиночное число. Что вы с ним дальше делаете нам же неизвестно.

Comment: Поправил пост. Функция должна вернуть индекс, на эту позицию помещается элемент

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что hash_table вначале пуста и её длина 0 соответственно?

Comment: @CrazyElf да, пуста

Comment: Но тогда при домножении на len(hash_table) будет ближе к 0 поначалу выдавать значения. С ростом таблицы значения будут более равномерно распределяться.